# Create a map with clickable provinces/states using SVG for a Flutter App ( android and Ios Phones)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, maps, interactive

I want to know how I can make an interactive map that I can incorporate into my Flutter app project.

The states and other subdivisions should be clickable and the name and other infos will pop up and so on.

I saw this SVC map customization with webflow and I want to know how to merge that with flutter:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz_6IBfCtBQ

Or is there a whole other better way to do that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/fc8c1bcc0a4fe67f04b05f3bb0c35e37

Comment: Thank you very much, What are all the points in static final? should i change the points for a new map? How do you assign shapes to a name?

Comment: this is what you have in SVG: <path d=...> or something similar, shapes are assigned to names in `_shapes` list